# Knockout unable to process biding for 'foreach'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am new to knockout. For my problem, I am trying to make it so that for each project, there is a button and textarea. The textarea will be hidden upon page load. If I click the button, it will show the textarea, or hide it (toggle). I have the following code implemented, but I am getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function
>   (){return projects }" Message: Unable to process binding "visible:
>   function (){return show }" Message: show is not defined

View Model:

```
function ProjectViewModel(proj) {
            //console.log(proj);
            var self = this;
            self.projects = ko.observableArray(proj);
            self.show = ko.observable(false);
            self.toggleTextArea = function () {
                self.show(!self.show());
            };
        };
```

HTML:

```
                <!-- ko foreach: projects -->
            <div id="eachOppyProject" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: '/tools/oppy/' + guid }" style="font-size: 25px;"><span class="link" data-bind="    value: guid, text: name"></span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-bind="text: projectDescription"></tr>
<%--                    <tr data-bind="text: guid"></tr>--%>
                </tbody>
            </table>
                 <span class="forminputtitle">Have you done project this before?</span>  <input type="button" value="Yes" data-bind="click: $parent.toggleTextArea" class="btnOppy"/>
                <textarea placeholder="Tell us a little of what you've done." data-bind="visible: show, attr: {'id': guid }" class="form-control newSessionAnalyst" style="height:75px; " /><br />
                <span> <input type="checkbox" name="oppyDoProjectAgain" style="padding-top:10px; padding-right:20px;">I'm thinking about doing this again. </span>
            <br />
                </div><br />
                <!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part of the error you're getting is:

> Message: show is not defined

This is happening where you're calling:

```
data-bind="visible: show ... "
```

This is happening because Knockout is trying to look for a variable named `show` within your `projects` object, but it isn't finding one as `show` and `projects` are both children of `ProjectViewModel`.

To reference `show`, you can use `$parent.show` instead:

```
data-bind="visible: $parent.show ... "
```

Comment: I added `$parent` to `toggleTextArea` but didn't think to add it to `show`. Thanks. This has introduced a new problem now: when I click the button to show the textarea, it shows ALL textareas on the page rather than just the corresponding one. Is there a way to link a unique identifier to toggling so it displays the correct textarea?